# Как в WordPress установить custom_permalink (модуль custom permalink)

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как работать с модулем Custom Permalink для WordPress. Делаю импорт рубрик (переношу сайт на новый движок) и, чтобы сохранить урл, использую этот модуль. Вот код вставки нового адреса. Пока новичок в этом деле. Кто-нибудь знает, как программно правильно туда вставить значение https://prnt.sc/kar4v2 ?

```
wp_update_term(7454, 'category', array(
    'custom_permalink' => '1223' 
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитав документацию и изучив структуру плагина, можно понять его работу.
Несколько заметок:

- Плагин пишет кастомные пермалинки в БД таблицу _options и хранит их в виде масива
- Для постов, он(плагин) сохраняет пермалинк в метаключах

Сейчас ниже, я наведу пример наиболие правильного метода автоматического добавления кастомного пермалинка для тегов(для категорий нужно будет заменить в примере на етапе проверки существования term `post_tag` на `category`).

Итак, если у нас уже созданы(у Вас импортированы) все категории или теги:

```
function set_tag_alias($tag, $alias){
    $set = false; // Результат
    $term = term_exists( $tag,'post_tag'); // Проверяем существование term-a
    if ( 0 !== $term && null !== $term ) { // Если он существует
        $obj = get_term(intval($term['term_id'])); // Получаем его ID, обезательно передаем как integer во избежания очень интерестного бага
        $table = get_option( 'custom_permalink_table' ); // Получаем уже сусщестующие кастомные пермалинки плагина
        if ( $alias) { // Если мы указали новый пермалинк, допишем его настройки в таблицу настроек плагина
            $table[$alias] = array(
                'id' => $obj->term_id,
                'kind' => ( $obj->taxonomy == 'category' ? 'category' : 'tag' ),
                'slug' => $obj->slug
            );
        }
        update_option( 'custom_permalink_table', $table ); // Сохраним наши дополнения
        $set = true; // Сменим результат на "Успешно"
    }
    return $set; 
}
```

Если всё хорошо, функция вернет результат `true`.

В примере выше, передаем аргументы для функции, где `$tag` - название тега\категории(в случаии работы с категориями), тоесть его `title`, например "Входные Двери", также не забываем перед передачей, обрезать пробелы вначале и в конце строки функцией `trim()`.

Пареметр `$alias` - желаемый новый пермалинк тега\категории, небзательно для даного плагина обрезать слешы вконце и начале строки, перед передачей параметра используем тот же `trim($alias,"/")`.

Манипуляции с паремтрами выше(`$tag`, `$alias`) также можно проделать внутри написаной мной функции выше модифицировав её.

Также, если нужен "полный фарш", можно поставить условие, что делать если тега\категории "Входные Двери" не существует в ситсеме, чтобы WordPress автоматически создавал его и возвращал `term_id` созданого тега\категории нашей функции далее по логике описаной выше. Также, неплохо проверять на ошибки выполнение сохранения новых настроек.

Я в примере описал минимальную логику согласно заданого вопроса, учитесь и развивайтесь.